# onClick doesn't work When using Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

I'm trying to show a Modal Box , I have an Image That When user Clicks on it , it will show The Modal Box,

it Works perfectly when using Chrome , but unfortunately it fails when using IE.

HTML :

```
<div id="pin" class="tooltip"> 
  <img onclick="document.getElementById('modal').style.display='block'"
   src="pin.png" width="40" height="40">
  <span class="tooltiptext">Show</span>
</div>

<div class="gallery animate" id="modal">
  <div class="content">
    <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('modal').style.
    display='none'">&times;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of IE? Note, IE has been discontinued, and has always notoriously been horrible at supporting anything.

Comment: And instead of using inline code, you should really be programmatically attaching listeners.

Comment: Who uses IE anymore ? get over it.

Comment: Are there any console errors being logged?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'v tried both nothing worked :(
IE 11

Comment: @SlimShady don't you think that the website should be adaptable with all browsers ?

Comment: Their is no errors being logged :( @arjabbar

Comment: @Moawyahks barely anyone uses IE nowdays . they use it only to download chrome/firefox. only in windows. even windows has edge now. but if you want to run then use it in js instead inline. but dont really care about IE unless you have some really big company like google and want to support everything

Comment: @SlimShady Thank you , I think i'll just get over it :)

Comment: @Moawyahks, Is your `modal` id DOM-unique? Also, can you post a [complete, but minimal and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead wrap the document.getElementById('modal').style.display='block'

In a Js function and then call the function in onclick event